# Can we be prohibited from downloading from Ubuntu software center?

Tags: software-center, downloads

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows Asus computer after it crashed totally and Windows got wiped out.

I managed to install Ubuntu on a USB and put it on my Asus but I think the computer still has many errors preventing Ubuntu from working optimally.

I can still use the basic programs with the installation but whenever I go to the software center it will not let me download new software or updates. It stops the download and says there was error due to file system corruption.

Is there a way to fix this and find out where the system is still corrupted?

I would appreciate a tutorial or screen shots of what I need to do so I can understand.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/fsck.8.html

Comment: i did fsck but it found no disk errors, but when i ran sudo apt-get install -f in terminal then it had two errors assosciated with thunderbird and libreoffice.

Comment: do __man fsck__ to see what its used for and __man apt__ to see what __apt-get__ is used for

Comment: I think we're going to need a screenshot or text paste of the error (text preferred).

Comment: oh i figured out that it was not working because i had third party installations allowed in the software and updates menu. when i changed that then i was able to download. but now i have a new problem. somehow i lost ubuntu on my system and i can't re-install it.